# Android 2.3 Progressive Download Not Working

Tags: android, video, mp4, codec, android-2.3-gingerbread

Does work:

```
http://clips.vorwaerts-gmbh.de/big_buck_bunny.mp4
```

Doesn't work:

```
http://media.lakewood.org.edgesuite.net/JOM/messages/564_750.mp4
```

Code used:

```
Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, uri);
intent.setDataAndType(uri, "video/mp4");
MainActivity.instance.startActivity(intent);
```

I checked the codec types in VLC and they are identical. However, in the dev tools in chrome (network tab) I noticed that the bunny video works like a progressive download while the joel video comes down in chunks (even though it's supposed to be progressive).

Is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference is, the first is using progressive streaming, whereas the second is using live streaming which is only supported from 3.0 and up. See here for the supported protocols:-

http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html#network

You've spotted that the second link gets downloaded in small chunks, which is a sign of live streaming (even if the content isn't necessary live). More on this protocol can be found here:-

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_Live_Streaming

The first appears to be using progressive streaming, which is not really streaming, it downloads the complete mp4 as one file, but does allow playback to be started as soon as you have enough buffered.

Hope that helps.

Ryan

Comment: that's what I thought too, but then I download the file (150mb) which wouldn't be allowed if it were streaming, and hosted it on my local host and the network traffic was identical. Kinda nuts..

Comment: big_buck_bunny.mp4 is 5.5 on download and 564_750.mp4 is 150 on download. I'm just viewing the url in chrome and hitting CMD/CTRL + S to save the file to my desktop.

Comment: yeah that is kinda nuts. as you have the mp4 downloaded have you tried copying to the sdcard and playing from there? May give you a clue to the issue. Other things are resolution, framerate, bitrate, etc. Support for that is device dependent. Also, the docs say "the moov atom must precede any mdat atoms, but must succeed the ftyp atom." which you could confirm if you have the file local.

Comment: Hey Ryan, I found the problem (in my answer). +1 for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

Found the problem.

## 564_750.mp4

- 1 video stream: AVC
- 1 audio stream: AAC
- 1 text stream: EIA-608 `<-- // problem`

The video was re-encoded without that text track it worked just fine.

Comment: Thanks for posting this, that will be useful knowledge one day!